# How can I get the Mercurial Changeset ID from a revision number?

Tags: mercurial

If I use `hg grep` I get a filename and a revision number.  How can I transform these bits of information to a changeset identifier that I can use in other commands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `hg id` or `hg log`:

```
$ hg id -r 100
526722d24ee5
$ hg log -r 100
changeset:   100:526722d24ee5
user:        jake@edge2.net
date:        Fri May 13 17:48:10 2005 -0700
summary:     reorganize code into classes
```

But please note that you *don't have to convert the revision number*. All Mercurial commands that take a changeset ID also take a revision number. They're interchangeable, as explained in [`hg help revisions`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revisions). This means that you can use a tag, a branch name, a bookmark, a revision number, or a changeset ID everywhere.

It is only if you need to communicate with other people that you really need the changeset IDs. The revision numbers are local and so my revision 100 can be different from your revision 100. So use the changeset ID in emails, bugtrackers, etc.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and pointing out you can use the revision or changeset id.

Comment: To clarify "communicate with other people" includes any other clone of the repo, INCLUDING other repos on your own machine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `id` command to change a (local) revision number into the hash:

```
hg id -r {your rev #}
```

It goes the other way to with the `-n` switch:

```
hg id -n -r {your rev hash}
```

Check out `hg help id` for all the fun!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the changeset may contain a `+` at the end, which indicates (I think) that the working directory is modified since the last commit.

i.e., it can look like this:

```
ed588733698a+
```

In many cases however you don't want to `+` in the string which may break any kind of scripting.

**You can get the plain changeset like this:**

```
hg id --template "{id|short}"
```

whose outputt will look like:

```
ed588733698a
```